# adb のエラー現象について

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, adb

Windows10でAndroidアプリを作成中に急に実機での実行ができなくなりました。
Android studioの再インストールやPCの再起動、Android端末の再起動など試しましたが治らず、
さらに色々確認したところイベントビューアーにADBのエラーが出ていました。

原因はADBだと思い、さらに色々試行錯誤をしたところ、adb.exeをリネームし、再度adb.exeをリネームし直したところ、
実機での実行が可能になりました。
ですが数時間すると再発してしまいました。

解決策は何かありませんでしょうか。

**追記**

イベントビューアーの全般タグには以下のように出力されています。
その後、本日に至るまで再度の発生はなく、一時的なものなのかもしれません。

```
障害が発生しているアプリケーション名: adb.exe、バージョン: 0.0.0.0、タイム スタンプ: 0x4019b211
障害が発生しているモジュール名: ucrtbase.dll、バージョン: 10.0.19041.789、タイム スタンプ: 0x82dc99a2
例外コード: 0xc0000409
障害オフセット: 0x0009eddb
障害が発生しているプロセス ID: 0x2e70
障害が発生しているアプリケーションの開始時刻: 0x01d86a8e8953db9c
障害が発生しているアプリケーション パス: C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
障害が発生しているモジュール パス: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
レポート ID: 4b22b8c3-2bab-4397-abd4-8823499abcea
障害が発生しているパッケージの完全な名前: 
障害が発生しているパッケージに関連するアプリケーション ID:
```

Comment: イベントビューアには具体的にどのようなエラーが出ていましたか？あくまで推測ですが、セキュリティソフトが制限をかけている可能性が考えられます。 adb は理解して使っている分には良いのですが、使い方次第でセキュリティリスクにもなりうるので警告や制限をかけるセキュリティソフトが多いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studioを再起動したら再発生したので、再度調査したところ、以下のリンク先の対応で解消しました。

[Android studio cant reach ADB server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71361005/19176985)

> 1-file -> 2-setting -> -3Build, Execution, Deployment -> 4-Debugger -> untick "Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging"